# Change Crystal Reports db ip address in vb.net

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, crystal-reports

I am currently using VB.net for getting the reports in need with Crystal Reports, My access to the SQL database server is using windows authentication , and what i need to do is to be able to change the IP address of the database source , as i am accessing a test server now , and the code will go somewhere else for work.

What i've found:
this is the only way to change the database source
CrReport.SetDatabaseLogon("user", "password", "server", "RJCards")
but then again i am using windows authentication.

P.S: when i am changing the datasource on the report it self its working great, but since we moving the application to another place, it needs to be set manually like to be retrived from a variable or something.

here is a look over my code

```
Private Sub GetDuplicatedFF()
        Dim CrReport As New DuplicatedFF
        Dim CrExportOptions As ExportOptions
        CrExportOptions = CrReport.ExportOptions
        Try
            CrReport.SetDatabaseLogon("user", "password", "server", "RJCards")
            CrReport.ExportToDisk(ExportFormatType.Excel, My.Settings.defaultDir & "\DuplicatedFF_" & Format(Now.Date, "yyyyMMdd") & ".xls")
            'My.Settings.defaultDir & "\DuplicatedFF_" & Format(Now.Date, "yyyyMMdd") & ".xls"
            MsgBox("Done Exporting your file")
        Catch err As Exception
            MessageBox.Show(err.Message)
        End Try
    End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use windows authentication or credentials to access a database through Crystal Reports, that means that the data retrieval SQL statements will be included inside the rpt file. This doesn't give you too much flexibility in scenarios where you need to make changes to IP addresses, database names, etc.

There is a different approach of providing data to the report with the use of a DataSet as a source. You simply add the necessary DataTables with the necessary columns to a DataSet, fill it with data and provide it to the report. So the rpt file won't include any 
embedded information (such as SQL statements).

In order to convert an existing report file to use the aforementioned approach, you can use the following steps:

1. Create an xsd file in your application (Add New Item... → Data → DataSet)
2. Edit the DataSet and add the necessary DataTable(s) (Right click → Add → DataTable)
3. Edit the DataTable(s) and add the necessary column(s) (Right click on DataTable → Add → Column)
4. Edit each column and set its properties such as DataType etc (Left click on column → Change property inside property window)
5. Now you need to edit the report file and change the Datasource location (Double click on the report → left click on Database Fields in Field Explorer → Set Datasource Location...)
6. As a Datasource replacement choose ADO.NET (XML) and double click on Make New Connection. Choose the filepath of the xsd file (DataSet) and press finish.
7. Each DataTable must be paired with an existing Table inside "Current Data source:" by selecting the pair and pressing the Update button.

Now the report file will just have the necessary placeholders (columns) without any database connection or SQL statements. To load data to the report, use the code below (changed according to your needs).

```
Imports System.Data.SqlClient

Public Class Form1

    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        'Windows Authentication Connection String'
        Dim ConnString As String = "Server=MyServer;Database=MyDb;Trusted_Connection=Yes;"
        'The SQL statement to retrieve data'
        Dim SqlStatement As String =
            <SQL>
                SELECT
                    [column1]
                    ,[column2]
                    ,[column3]
                FROM [MyDb].[dbo].[MyTable]
            </SQL>
        'A new instance to the DataSet that we created'
        Dim MyDataSet As New DataSet2
        'A new instance to the report file'
        Dim MyReport As New CrystalReport1
        'A new instance to the SQL adapter'
        Dim SqlAdapter As New SqlDataAdapter(SqlStatement, ConnString)
        'Fills the DataTable with data retrieved from the database'
        SqlAdapter.Fill(MyDataSet.Tables("TestTable1"))
        'Sets the DataSet as the report source'
        MyReport.SetDataSource(MyDataSet)
        'Previews the report'
        CrystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = MyReport
    End Sub

End Class
```

Comment: I really appriciate such a clear answer , fixed the whole code as guided and it worked as intended. thanks alot :)